# how to login into phpbb software by passing username and pwd via url

Tags: php, phpbb3

I have installed the phpbb software and i am new to it,
     if a user access the forum via url like http://192.168.1.162/payodatalk/service/login.php?mode=login&username=uname&pwd=123

```
 Where can i find the session variables like user name and password initialized ? i have referred the PHPBB site but still i am not clear about it. Any help on this would be useful for me.
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not allow authentication through GET request, since the requests would not be idempotent (cfr [Hypertext Transfer Protocol - Method definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)).

However, to allow this you should modify phpBB's login function to fetch username and password from the $_GET supervariable instead of $_POST only (you should check $_GET if $_POST does not contain username and password, do not replace the $_POST entirely).

Comment: where to do that modification ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by changing the base code.. 
For that read the code structure of phpBB [here](http://area51.phpbb.com/docs/code/30x/)

but its not safe to include pwd in the url itself .

Consider a user logs in as u specified and anyone who able to see the url from browser history can also login..

Thats a bad technique to be online and its actually reverse to the concept of authentication.